# travis build failing because devtools is missing

Tags: r, travis-ci, devtools

I'm trying to setup a travis build but it fails with the error below:

```
$ export PKG_TARBALL=$(Rscript -e 'pkg <- devtools::as.package("."); cat(paste0(pkg$package, "_", pkg$version, ".tar.gz"));')
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
```

My package doesn't need `devtools` to compile.

I've added `devtools` to `Suggests:` in the `DESCRIPTION`, added it to `.travis.yml` (see below) be no avail.

```
language: r
sudo: required
# System dependencies for HTTP calling
apt_packages:
 - libcurl4-openssl-dev
 - libxml2-dev
r_binary_packages:
  - devtools
install:
  - Rscript -e 'install.packages("INLA", repos="http://www.math.ntnu.no/inla/R/stable")'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Log file of the failing build: https://travis-ci.org/ThierryO/multimput/builds/97625211

Source of the package: https://github.com/ThierryO/multimput/tree/travis

Comment: Try using Craig Citro's guide [here](https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis/wiki), many R packages do. I'm surprised that didn't come up in Google...

Comment: I've been using https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r. It claims to be the official support of R on Travis. It mentions [r-travis](https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis) under "Converting from r-travis". Therefore I ignored Craig Citro's guide.

Comment: I see. I'm sure this can be done by sticking to the official documentation alone, but I think the aforementioned guide / associated scripts will save you a lot of grief (it did for me). FWIW many high profile packages use it (e.g. Rcpp, dplyr, ...), so it will presumably continue to be well-maintained in the future.

Comment: Many users reported devtools install errors on the [travis-ci issues list](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5650). In a reply, @jimhester recommended using container based builds instead of the old procedure.

Comment: did you ever figure out a fix for this? I am having the same issue with `testthat`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm managed to get it up and running with the `.travis.yml` according to the [official Travis CI documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r). The solution has several components:

- install devtools manually
- install CRAN dependencies manually
- install INLA manually with both the `math.ntnu.no` and `rstudio.com` repositories. The second is required because the first has only the INLA packages and not it's dependencies.

[Build log](https://travis-ci.org/ThierryO/multimput/builds/97996845)

`.travis.yml`

```
language: r
sudo: required
install:
  - Rscript -e 'install.packages("devtools", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com")'
  - Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("plyr", "geepack", "snowfall"), repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com")'
  - Rscript -e 'install.packages("INLA", repos = c("http://www.math.ntnu.no/inla/R/stable", "http://cran.rstudio.com"))'
```