# Non-standard Remotes package INLA in R package

Tags: r, r-package

I have a package that Requires [INLA](https://www.r-inla.org/download-install), which is not hosted on CRAN or a standard GitHub repository. There are multiple SO questions detailing how to install the package on a personal machine, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66622811/problems-installing-the-inla-package), or even mentions it as a [dependency in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353215/travis-build-failing-because-devtools-is-missing/34396229#34396229).

The two ways that are typically recommended to install on a personal machine are:

#### Direct from INLA website

```
install.packages("INLA",repos=c(getOption("repos"),INLA="https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable"), dep=TRUE)
```

#### From the GitHub host

```
devtools::install_github(repo = "https://github.com/hrue/r-inla", ref = "stable", subdir = "rinla", build = FALSE)
```

Now, these are fine for personal machines, but don't work in the DESCRIPTION files `Remotes:` section.

If we do `url::https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable`, this gives an error that the file extension isn't recognized.

```
 Error: Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  Don't know how to decompress files with extension
```

If we do `github::hrue/r-inla`, I am unaware of how to pass (or if it's even possible) the `ref`, `subdir`, and `build` arguments in the DESCRIPTION file.

Previous packages used a read only mirror of the INLA code that was hosted on GitHub, solely for this purpose, at this [repo](https://github.com/inbo/INLA) and then just using `github::inbo/INLA`. However, this repository is out of date.

#### Current solution

What I'm doing instead is to directly reference the tarball hosted on the main webpage.

```
url::https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable/src/contrib/INLA_21.02.23.tar.gz
```

This solution works, and passes CI as well as the machines are able to install and load from there. The only issue is that I need to periodically update the static link to this tarball, and would prefer to reference the stable build, either directly from the INLA website as above, or the `hrue/inla` repo with those other arguments passed. Directly referencing those links also has the advantage that when my package is re-installed on a machine, it would recognize whether or not the latest version of INLA has been installed on that machine. Is there a way to achieve this in the DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: Hi! Did you check the approach adopted by [inlabru](https://github.com/inlabru-org/inlabru/)? See [here](https://github.com/inlabru-org/inlabru/blob/devel/DESCRIPTION)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a perfect answer but maybe what you can do is add the `zip` url of the stable branch of `INLA` from the new github repository of `INLA`:-

```
url::https://github.com/hrue/r-inla/archive/refs/heads/stable.zip
```

Hence, this will always install the latest stable version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the following line to your `DESCRIPTION` file.

```
Additional_repositories: https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable
```